# Trying to get the direct children but getting all children using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get create a dictionary of categories especially a food from this [url](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/build-with-foursquare/categories/). Now, when I am trying to use the below code, it is giving repetitive `li` items.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/build-with-foursquare/categories/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text)

food_categories = soup.select('div.documentTemplate__Content-sc-5mpekp-0 > ul > li:nth-child(4)')[0]

for tagli in food_categories.find_all("li"):
    print(tagli.find('h3').text)
    for another_tagli in tagli.find_all('ul'):
        for some_tagli in another_tagli.find_all('li'):
            print(some_tagli.find('h3').text)
            for one_tagli in some_tagli.find_all('ul'):
                for aon_tagli in one_tagli.find_all('li'):
                    print(aon_tagli.find('h3').text)
```

Now, as per many stackoverflow posts, I have tried to use `recursive=False` argument to get the only direct children, but if I use that I get nothing.

I am looking for an output something like this:

```
{
  'food': {
    'Afghan Restaurant': [],
    'African Restaurant': ['Ethiopian Restaurant'],
    'Asian Restaurant': {
      'Chinese Restaurant': ['Anhui Restaurant', 'Beijing Restaurant']
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly guide me here.

Comment: What is the output that is required?

Comment: @BittoBennichan, I have updated my question with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/build-with-foursquare/categories/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text)

food_categories = soup.select('div.documentTemplate__Content-sc-5mpekp-0 > ul > li:nth-child(4)')[0]

data={}

for tagli in food_categories.find_all(recursive=False):

    data[tagli.find('h3').text]={}

    for some_tagli in tagli.find('ul').find_all(recursive=False):
        data[tagli.find('h3').text][some_tagli.find('h3').text]={}

        for aon_tagli in some_tagli.find('ul').find_all(recursive=False):

            data[tagli.find('h3').text][some_tagli.find('h3').text][aon_tagli.find('h3').text]=[]
            for  taglis in aon_tagli.find('ul').find_all(recursive=False):
                data[tagli.find('h3').text][some_tagli.find('h3').text][aon_tagli.find('h3').text].append(taglis.find('h3').text)



print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I needed output in specific format which I have added in my question. Kindly check.

Comment: yeah, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

This script produces the tree from the Food sub-category:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_tree(t):
    dct = {}

    for li in t.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        dct[li.find_next('h3').text] = parse_tree(li.select_one('ul'))

    return dct

url = 'https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/build-with-foursquare/categories/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
root = soup.select_one('h3:contains("Food") ~ ul')

tree = parse_tree(root)

# pretty print the tree:
import json
print(json.dumps(tree, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Afghan Restaurant": {},
    "African Restaurant": {
        "Ethiopian Restaurant": {}
    },
    "American Restaurant": {
        "New American Restaurant": {}
    },
    "Asian Restaurant": {
        "Burmese Restaurant": {},
        "Cambodian Restaurant": {},
        "Chinese Restaurant": {
            "Anhui Restaurant": {},
            "Beijing Restaurant": {},
            "Cantonese Restaurant": {},
            "Cha Chaan Teng": {},
            "Chinese Aristocrat Restaurant": {},

    ... and so on.
```